# React Native: Fetch data and write the response in custom js file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can I fetch data and put the response as a const in another js file like language.js

Comment: What problems did you encounter when you tried it? What benefits do you hope to achieve by doing it? Please see [ask]. It's very rare that a one line question has all the necessary information to be answered on this site.

Comment: Thank you @BrianThompson, yes I get your point.
Actually, I need to implement multilanguage on mobile application. I use a library called Localization which use a js file (languages.js) and you put all your labels as a JSON file like this:

const LocalizedStrings = {
       'ar': {
            "label1": "text_ar",
         },
        'en': {
            "label1": "text_en"
          }
}


now I create the labels in CMS and I create an api that get all the labels as a response match the schema of localizedstrings.

So I need to call this api in my react native application